# Play audio sound on an event as notification sound, Wear OS?

Tags: android, wear-os

How to play bell sound on an event other than notifications on wear OS. I am able to play music using MediaPlayer API. But when I change the Stream type to

mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

It says warning stream types are deprevcated.

What is the proper way of to play notification like the sound?

Comment: Follow the steps specified in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#ReadChannel), also take note that there only some instances like setting the channel importance to `Urgent` or `High` that the device will make sounds, [see description here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance).

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 thanks for the response I don't want to show notification, still I want to play beep like audio, Isn't there any way using MediaPlayer API ?